# Deploying solr in Jboss

Tags: jboss, solr

I want to deploy the solr.war to jboss server.
Please provide me the steps for this.
Also after deploying what url i should use to access the solr/data/index directory?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find some info: [Deploy solr in JBoss](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJBoss)

Please tell us which version of solr and JBoss you're using and if you need extra help.

Comment: Hey thanks Volothamp.
I am using apache-solr-1.4.0 and Jboss-server 4.6.
I have already followed these steps and i think the solr is deployed.
But when i try to search the indexes on this server from my web application i get following error in jboss logs :
09:49:50,936 ERROR [SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unsupported content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:258)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(Message...

Answer (score 2):

In JBoss 7.1.1:

1. In jboss-as-7.1.1.Final-folder/standalone/deployments COPY **solr.war** and **solr** directory from examples folder of solr release.
2. JBoss Administration console(probably localhost:8080) -> Profile -> System properties: KEY-> solr.solr.home VALUE->
3. Run server and test localhost:8080/solr/.

Comment: where did you get that key name from? The docs all say solr/home, which does not work on jboss. Wouldn't ever guessed that one (thanks a lot).

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a post in portuguese...

http://jbossdivers.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/deployando-apache-solr-4-2-1-no-jboss-as-7-1-3-jboss-eap-6-0-1/